# Wordpress endpoint for edit customer throws 404

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

I am using http://www.internationalopal.com/my-account/edit-account like it said on the wordpress site directly.  When I use the edit-account endpoint it throws a 404.  I am using woocommerce 2.1.3 if that helps.  Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: do you have permalinks on? on site it look like you have set to default (without .htaccess) and the link looks like premalinks are set to postname (with .htaccess)